# How to record and stream video from local device webcam(like laptop or PC) and store that video in AWS S3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-kinesis, amazon-kinesis-video-streams

I'm currently developing a web application in ReactJS, where a user can record a session with his webcam and stream it to AWS infra. I have come across [Amazon Kinesis Video Streams with WebRTC](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-webrtc). Whereby creating SignalingChannel a user can stream that data to AWS master and viewer model.

But I want to store that session of a user in some persistent storage like AWS S3. So that the session can be reviewed later by the reviewer.

Wanted to know if I'm correct for using AWS KVS ? and what will be the possible steps to store the video on S3?

Comment: AWS has a dedicated solution for exactly this use case: https://aws.amazon.com/mediastore/